# Sum of Primes between two number from Optimized Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: java, optimization, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Here is the code that i wrote that is working for me to give me sum of prime numbers between `n` and `m`.

```
class TestClass {
    final static int MAX=1000000;
    final static boolean[] isPrime=isPrime();
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader keyboard= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t=Integer.parseInt(keyboard.readLine());

        while(t>0 && t<=100){
            String[] tempInt=keyboard.readLine().split(" ");
            int n=Integer.parseInt(tempInt[0]);
            int m=Integer.parseInt(tempInt[1]);

            int sum=primeSum(n,m);
            System.out.println(sum);
            t--;
        }
    }

private static int primeSum(int n, int m) {
        int sum=0;

        for(int i=n;i<=m;i++){
            if(isPrime[i]){
                sum=sum+i;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static boolean[] isPrime(){
        int maxFactor= (int)Math.sqrt(MAX);
        boolean[] isPrime=new boolean[MAX + 1];
        int len=isPrime.length;
        Arrays.fill(isPrime,true);
        isPrime[0]=false;
        isPrime[1]=false;
        for(int i=0;i<=maxFactor;i++){
            if(isPrime[i]){
                for(int j=i+i;j<len;j+=i){
                    isPrime[j]=false;
                }
            }
        }
        return isPrime;

    }

}
```

Input:

```
2
1 99999
10000 99999
```

Output:

```
454396537
448660141
```

Now i'm trying to *further optimize sieve by just taking odd number* what usually in practice.
Here is the Optimized Sieve function  that i have written

```
private static boolean[] isPrime(){
        int root=(int) Math.sqrt(MAX)+1;
        int limit=(MAX-1)/2;
        boolean[] isPrime=new boolean[limit];
        Arrays.fill(isPrime, true);
        root = root/2 -1;
        for(int i = 0; i < root ; i++){
            if(isPrime[i]){
                for( int j = 2*i*(i+3)+3 , p = 2*i+3; j < limit ; j=j+p ){
                    isPrime[j]=false;
                }
            }
        }

    return isPrime;
}
```

Which i was able to do. I tested the above function till `MAX=100`. Here is the Ideone Link [IDEONE LINK](http://ideone.com/igwgF2)
Test Result

```
    truetruetruefalsetruetruefalsetruetruefalsetruefalsefalsetruetruefalsefalsetrue
falsetruetruefalsetruefalsefalsetruefalsefalsetruetruefalsefalsetruefalse
truetruefalsefalsetruefalsetruefalsefalsetruefalsefalsefalsetruefalse
```

i.e 3 5 7 9̶ 11 13 1̶5̶ 17 19 ̶2̶1̶  23 2̶5̶ ̶2̶7̶  29 31 ̶3̶3̶ ̶3̶5̶ ̶  37 3̶9̶ ̶  so on..

Now what really bugging me is the indexing i did in `primeSum() method` for this optimized sieve

```
private static int primeSum(int n, int m) {
        int sum;
        if(n>0 && n<=2){
            sum=2;
        }else
            sum=0;
        //System.out.println(sum);
        for( int i = (n-3)/2; i <= (m-3)/2 ; i++){
            if(isPrime[i]){
                //System.out.println(i);
                sum=sum+2*i+3;
            }
        }
        return sum;
    }
```

But as obvious this indexing of `n` is failing for `n<3`. so i have to do this to get this code working

```
if(n>0 && n<=2){
            sum=2;
            n=n+2;
        }
```

But then it still failing for the cases when i've to find it between ranges

```
1 2
1 1
2 2
```

So should i again include these cases and deal with it separately ?, Is my way of doing the indexing `i` in `primeSum()` method is proper ? or can i get it done in more good way ? and what are the other possible way of indexing here ?

Comment: Probably a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @reto oK Moving it their :)

Comment: You may want to delete it here.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you loop for every odd number between `n` and `m`:

```
private static int primeSum(int n, int m) {
    int sum = 0;
    if (n <= 2 && m >= 2)  // need this because 2 not in isPrime
        sum += 2;
    if (n%2 == 0)  // always start from an odd number
        n++;
    for (int i = n; i <= m; i += 2) {
        int index = (i - 3)/2;
        if (index >= 0 && isPrime[index]) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```